# Camera is rendering in another collection

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine

I am using version 2.8 and Eevee to render. When I try to render my scene it goes blank. What I mean by that is that it just renders the background. I tried changing the active camera by control and number pad 0, but no change. I then tried going to the scene tab in the properties window and changing the camera. I then tried deleting all cameras but one. I thought that maybe somehow I am inside an object so I made everything but what I wanted to render invisible in the viewport and in the render. After each time I tried something I thought could be a solution I kept staring at a blank solid background.

Edit: Here's a link. http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52107

Comment: The best place to upload your .blend files is here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out after a good night's rest. The "Display in render" option (Camera Icon) is hidden by default. In the outliner on the top right there is a drop-down menu that shows you all the restrictions you can toggle, (Selectable, Hide in the viewport, et cetera) and there it was "Display in render." It's the camera icon.